# What are some of the earliest examples of welfare states?

Tags: middle-ages, economy, classical-antiquity

I was reading about Welfare States and came across this on Wikipedia:

> Emperor Ashoka of India put forward his idea of a welfare state in the 3rd century BCE. [...] The concepts of welfare and pension were introduced in early Islamic law as forms of Zakat (charity), one of the Five Pillars of Islam, under the Rashidun Caliphate in the 7th century... The taxes (including Zakat and Jizya) collected in the treasury of an Islamic government were used to provide income for the needy, including the poor, elderly, orphans, widows, and the disabled. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welfare_state#History_of_welfare_states))

Beyond those two examples from pre-modern history, I wanted to know if there are more. And I also wanted to know the reasons why they (including the two examples already mentioned) stopped being welfare states. Was it just a regime change, or was it due to the model not being economically sustainable?

**What were the earliest examples of welfare states, what qualities did they have, and why did the end?**

Comment: I think it would help if you define better welfare states. If we call Zakat as welfare, we can arguably put many other religious or state taxes in this category, which then makes the answer very broad and useless.

Comment: @Greg My mistake, I cut off the quotation at the wrong place. I believe the income for the poor is what is called a welfare state by Wikipedia. But, I think the answers should define welfare state for their own purposes.

Comment: Definition from the wiki article you linked - "The welfare state is a form of government in which the state protects and promotes the economic and social well-being of the citizens, based upon the principles of equal opportunity, equitable distribution of wealth, and public responsibility for citizens unable to avail themselves of the minimal provisions for a good life." Pretty sure that caliphate might've qualified for the last principle, but not the first two. Besides, welfare isn't the only thing zakat money can be spent on - you'd need to check how the money was actually distributed.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov Seeing as I am asking for early examples of a welfare state, it will include those states that do not completely match the modern definition but fulfill many of the principles, most specifically the income for the poor.

Comment: @TheZ  Giving out money shouldn't be the only or main criteria: 1) We survey societies and ages where money didn't have such a central role as now. Even in the 21st-century free food, accommodation or free health care helps as much if not more eg a homeless person then some government pension. Also, without detailed governmental records and IDing systems giving out money to a large population is impossible. 2) Well-being is relative. In ages where hard work and an average job was bearly enough for surviving, " minimal provisions for a good life" is a rather relative concept.

Comment: @Greg I'm not talking about *money*. Collected zakat (regardless of form of payment), as far as I know, can be spent paying "those fighting for a religious cause or a cause of God" (jihadists?), or to persuade potental converts to Islam, amongst other things; and before all of those - to pay zakat collectors, with the rest distributed amongst all the groups equally. The way I see it - the result for impoverished (just one of many groups) would be the same as european church charity; i.e. limited opportunity to receive and ultimately not enough to make any difference.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov I do not think the Wikipedia article is calling Zakat itself as proof of welfare state. It is calling the income for the poor given in the early Caliphate as an example of a welfare state.

Comment: @TheZ well, after reading up on Caliphate - I can't find any mention of actual income for the poor (besides the zakat). I did find that the government was to stockpile food to be distributed in case of a famine; that can be called a welfare program, I guess.

Comment: Given that this is a “prove my anachronistic concept,” the answer is whatever you like. This isn’t how economic historians do theory.

Comment: Having some humanitarian policies and being a welfare state is two different things.

Comment: The Roman corn dole comes to mind. In antiquity, Rome distributed free or subsidised grain to the poorest ~200,000 of its citizens.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov I was talking about money because of the excessive reliance on "income for the poor" in the OPs argument when talking about ages where money wasn't what you really needed if you were really poor.

Comment: I am not sure you can have a welfare state prior to the Westphalia state...